# How best to use logging helpers in python to reflect the module they're called from

Tags: python, logging

I was writing a package in python that makes rest requests against an api over http.

I would prefer for the module (called kazoo) that handles the logic of talking to the kazoo api could be kept seperate from the logging helpers I'm using.

At first I was using the logging helpers in the same module `kazoo`, but thought it might be easier to maintain if I kept all logging related stuff in the logging module `log`.

When I moved the logging helpers to `log`, and then called them from `kazoo` the log lines reflect the `log` module, rather than the `kazoo`.  Because I found value in having the correct context for these kind of messages, I decided to move them back

I understand the way I'm using them this is expected behavior, but I was hoping someone might have an idea how this could be done better.

Attaching an edited version of the two files in the package that I'm dealing with.  I used to know python alot more but I just finished a 6 month project where I didn't use it at all, and I feel abit rusty on some of this stuff.

**log.py**

```
import logging

from create_account import config

def log_level_from_string(string):
    level = getattr(logging, string.upper())

    if not isinstance(level, int):
        raise ValueError('Invalid log level: %s' % level)

    return level


def init_logger():

    # set the requests library module level
    requests_level = log_level_from_string(config.REQUESTS_LOG_LEVEL)
    logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(requests_level)

    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    fh = logging.FileHandler(config.LOG_FILE)
    fh_level = log_level_from_string(config.FILE_LOG_LEVEL)
    fh.setLevel(fh_level)

    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch_level = log_level_from_string(config.CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL)
    ch.setLevel(ch_level)

    formatter = logging.Formatter(config.LOG_FORMAT)

    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger.addHandler(fh)
    logger.addHandler(ch)
    return logger

logger = init_logger()
```

**kazoo.py**

```
import json
import requests

from create_account import templates

import logging
logger = log.logging.getLogger(__name__)


# logging helpers
def log_request_for(request, name):
    if logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):
        logger.debug('%s request: url %s  headers %s  body %s', 
            name,
            request.url, 
            request.headers, 
            request.body)


def log_response_for(response, name):
    if logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):
        logger.debug('%s response: status %s  body %s', 
            name,
            response.status_code,
            response.json())

def log_error_for(error, name):
    logger.error('%s: (%s)', name, error)

def log_json_error_for(error_json, name):
    logger.error('%s: (%s)', name, json.dumps(error_json))


# Client for making API requests
class Client(object):
    _api_url = 'https://[redacted]'
    _authenticated = False

    <snip>

    def create_account(self, account_name=None, realm=None, timezone=None):

        verb = 'put'
        account = self._account_id
        endpoint = None
        headers = None
        template = 'new_account'
        variables = dict(account_name=account_name, 
                         realm=realm, 
                         timezone=timezone)

        req = self._api_request(verb, 
                                self._account_id, 
                                endpoint=endpoint, 
                                headers=headers, 
                                template=template, 
                                variables=variables)

        log_request_for(req.request, 'create_account')

        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        # test status_code (if)
        log_response_for(req, 'create_account')

        if req.status_code >= 400:

            if req.json().get('data'):
                edata = req.json()['data']
                log_json_error_for(edata, 'create_account')
            else:
                log_error_for(req.json(), 'create_account')
        else:
            # handle error

    <snip>
```

Comment: Hi, Joe, could you post your logging configuration file, please? Sorry your question has languished for a while.